# Eclipse IDE make: *** No rule to make target...... needed by 'core/abi.cpp.o'. Stop

Tags: c++, eclipse, arduino

I'm trying to make Arduino projects with eclipse IDE and I have followed this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtPvkPpAx0E) and I am getting this error:

```
Building ArduinoTest
make: *** No rule to make target 'Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/abi.cpp', needed by 'core/abi.cpp.o'.  Stop.
```

I'm new with this and I don't know what I could be doing wrong.

This is my makefile, it's the one that was generated by Eclipse:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
SHELL = $(ComSpec)
RMDIR = rmdir /s /q
RM = del /q
mymkdir = if not exist "$1" mkdir "$1"
else
RMDIR = rm -fr
RM = rm -f
mymkdir = mkdir -p $1
endif

PROJECT_OBJS = \
    project/ArduinoTest.cpp.o \

PLATFORM_CORE_OBJS = \
    core/abi.cpp.o \
    core/CDC.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o \
    core/hooks.c.o \
    core/IPAddress.cpp.o \
    core/main.cpp.o \
    core/new.cpp.o \
    core/PluggableUSB.cpp.o \
    core/Print.cpp.o \
    core/Stream.cpp.o \
    core/Tone.cpp.o \
    core/USBCore.cpp.o \
    core/WInterrupts.c.o \
    core/wiring.c.o \
    core/wiring_analog.c.o \
    core/wiring_digital.c.o \
    core/wiring_pulse.c.o \
    core/wiring_pulse.S.o \
    core/wiring_shift.c.o \
    core/WMath.cpp.o \
    core/WString.cpp.o \

PLATFORM_VARIANT_OBJS = \

LIBRARIES_OBJS = \

TARGETS = \
    ArduinoTest.hex \

all: $(TARGETS)

ArduinoTest.hex: ArduinoTest.elf
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "./ArduinoTest.elf" "./ArduinoTest.hex"

ArduinoTest.elf: $(PROJECT_OBJS) $(LIBRARIES_OBJS) core.a
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega2560  -o "./ArduinoTest.elf" $(PROJECT_OBJS) $(LIBRARIES_OBJS) "./core.a" "-L." -lm

core.a: $(PLATFORM_CORE_OBJS) $(PLATFORM_VARIANT_OBJS)

clean:
    -$(RMDIR) project core variant libraries
    -$(RM) *.hex *.eep *.bin *.elf *.a *.ar *.d

size:
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-size" -A "./ArduinoTest.elf"

project/ArduinoTest.cpp.o: ../../ArduinoTest.cpp project/ArduinoTest.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"

project/ArduinoTest.cpp.d: ;

-include project/ArduinoTest.cpp.d 


core/abi.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/abi.cpp core/abi.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/abi.cpp.d: ;

-include core/abi.cpp.d

core/CDC.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp core/CDC.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/CDC.cpp.d: ;

-include core/CDC.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp core/HardwareSerial.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.d

core/hooks.c.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/hooks.c core/hooks.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/hooks.c.d: ;

-include core/hooks.c.d

core/IPAddress.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp core/IPAddress.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/IPAddress.cpp.d: ;

-include core/IPAddress.cpp.d

core/main.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/main.cpp core/main.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/main.cpp.d: ;

-include core/main.cpp.d

core/new.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/new.cpp core/new.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/new.cpp.d: ;

-include core/new.cpp.d

core/PluggableUSB.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/PluggableUSB.cpp core/PluggableUSB.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/PluggableUSB.cpp.d: ;

-include core/PluggableUSB.cpp.d

core/Print.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/Print.cpp core/Print.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/Print.cpp.d: ;

-include core/Print.cpp.d

core/Stream.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp core/Stream.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/Stream.cpp.d: ;

-include core/Stream.cpp.d

core/Tone.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp core/Tone.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/Tone.cpp.d: ;

-include core/Tone.cpp.d

core/USBCore.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp core/USBCore.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/USBCore.cpp.d: ;

-include core/USBCore.cpp.d

core/WInterrupts.c.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c core/WInterrupts.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/WInterrupts.c.d: ;

-include core/WInterrupts.c.d

core/wiring.c.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/wiring.c core/wiring.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/wiring.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring.c.d

core/wiring_analog.c.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c core/wiring_analog.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/wiring_analog.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_analog.c.d

core/wiring_digital.c.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c core/wiring_digital.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/wiring_digital.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_digital.c.d

core/wiring_pulse.c.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c core/wiring_pulse.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/wiring_pulse.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_pulse.c.d

core/wiring_pulse.S.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.S
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -x assembler-with-cpp -flto -MMD -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/wiring_shift.c.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c core/wiring_shift.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/wiring_shift.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_shift.c.d

core/WMath.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp core/WMath.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/WMath.cpp.d: ;

-include core/WMath.cpp.d

core/WString.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino/WString.cpp core/WString.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.19/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.9.2-atmel3.5.4-arduino2/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/WString.cpp.d: ;

-include core/WString.cpp.d
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to what could be causing this error?

Comment: And what is your *specific* question?

Comment: I dont get why im getting that error, i followed the tutorial exactly, and now I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

That's a common problem when you have your computer username with spaces.

```
core/CDC.cpp.o: C:/Users/Bryam Ulloa/
```

I've extracted this from a random location of your makefile. Because the path is defined without `""` the compiler is interpreting that path as two smaller arguments instead of the full path. Try putting `""` around it, or, to save you from this kind of errors that are not always easy to fix as this one, do yourself a favor and use a space free username.