# how do i fix *** No rule to make target 'C:/Users/KlausBgamer', needed by 'core/abi.cpp.o'

Tags: c++, c, build, arduino, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to make Arduino projects with eclipse IDE and I have followed this video tutorial and I am getting this error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** No rule to make target 'C:/Users/KlausBgamer', needed by 'core/abi.cpp.o'.  Stop. IR_Conversor            C/C++ Problem

This is my Eclipse-generated makefile

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
SHELL = $(ComSpec)
RMDIR = rmdir /s /q
RM = del /q
mymkdir = if not exist "$1" mkdir "$1"
else
RMDIR = rm -fr
RM = rm -f
mymkdir = mkdir -p $1
endif

PROJECT_OBJS = \
    project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.o \

PLATFORM_CORE_OBJS = \
    core/abi.cpp.o \
    core/CDC.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o \
    core/hooks.c.o \
    core/IPAddress.cpp.o \
    core/main.cpp.o \
    core/new.cpp.o \
    core/PluggableUSB.cpp.o \
    core/Print.cpp.o \
    core/Stream.cpp.o \
    core/Tone.cpp.o \
    core/USBCore.cpp.o \
    core/WInterrupts.c.o \
    core/wiring.c.o \
    core/wiring_analog.c.o \
    core/wiring_digital.c.o \
    core/wiring_pulse.c.o \
    core/wiring_pulse.S.o \
    core/wiring_shift.c.o \
    core/WMath.cpp.o \
    core/WString.cpp.o \

PLATFORM_VARIANT_OBJS = \

LIBRARIES_OBJS = \

TARGETS = \
    IR_Conversor.hex \

all: $(TARGETS)

IR_Conversor.hex: IR_Conversor.elf
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "./IR_Conversor.elf" "./IR_Conversor.hex"

IR_Conversor.elf: $(PROJECT_OBJS) $(LIBRARIES_OBJS) core.a
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega2560   -o "./IR_Conversor.elf" $(PROJECT_OBJS) $(LIBRARIES_OBJS)  "./core.a" "-L." -lm

core.a: $(PLATFORM_CORE_OBJS) $(PLATFORM_VARIANT_OBJS)

clean:
    -$(RMDIR) project core variant libraries
    -$(RM) *.hex *.eep *.bin *.elf *.a *.ar *.d

size:
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-size" -A "./IR_Conversor.elf"

project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.o: ../../IRCONVERSO.cpp project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"

project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.d: ;

-include project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.d 


core/abi.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/abi.cpp core/abi.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/abi.cpp.d: ;

-include core/abi.cpp.d

core/CDC.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp core/CDC.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/CDC.cpp.d: ;

-include core/CDC.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp core/HardwareSerial.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.d

core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.d: ;

-include core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.d

core/hooks.c.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/hooks.c core/hooks.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"
    
core/hooks.c.d: ;

-include core/hooks.c.d

core/IPAddress.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp core/IPAddress.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/IPAddress.cpp.d: ;

-include core/IPAddress.cpp.d

core/main.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/main.cpp core/main.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/main.cpp.d: ;

-include core/main.cpp.d

core/new.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/new.cpp core/new.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/new.cpp.d: ;

-include core/new.cpp.d

core/PluggableUSB.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/PluggableUSB.cpp core/PluggableUSB.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/PluggableUSB.cpp.d: ;

-include core/PluggableUSB.cpp.d

core/Print.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/Print.cpp core/Print.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/Print.cpp.d: ;

-include core/Print.cpp.d

core/Stream.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp core/Stream.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/Stream.cpp.d: ;

-include core/Stream.cpp.d

core/Tone.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp core/Tone.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/Tone.cpp.d: ;

-include core/Tone.cpp.d

core/USBCore.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp core/USBCore.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/USBCore.cpp.d: ;

-include core/USBCore.cpp.d

core/WInterrupts.c.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c core/WInterrupts.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"
    
core/WInterrupts.c.d: ;

-include core/WInterrupts.c.d

core/wiring.c.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/wiring.c core/wiring.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"
    
core/wiring.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring.c.d

core/wiring_analog.c.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c core/wiring_analog.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"
    
core/wiring_analog.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_analog.c.d

core/wiring_digital.c.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c core/wiring_digital.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"
    
core/wiring_digital.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_digital.c.d

core/wiring_pulse.c.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c core/wiring_pulse.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"
    
core/wiring_pulse.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_pulse.c.d

core/wiring_pulse.S.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.S
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -x assembler-with-cpp -flto -MMD -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/wiring_shift.c.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c core/wiring_shift.c.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"
    
core/wiring_shift.c.d: ;

-include core/wiring_shift.c.d

core/WMath.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp core/WMath.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/WMath.cpp.d: ;

-include core/WMath.cpp.d

core/WString.cpp.o: C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino/WString.cpp core/WString.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"
    "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "./core.a" "$@"

core/WString.cpp.d: ;

-include core/WString.cpp.d
```

i saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956264/eclipse-ide-make-no-rule-to-make-target-needed-by-core-abi-cpp-o-s) that said i should use `""` at my username (KlausBgamer 13) in filepath but if i do it as soon as i run the build it goes back to the one without `""`, is this the error? and why is it auto corecting bak to wrong?

Comment: Do you have the choice of getting rid of spaces in your directory names?

Comment: The _link_ you posted deals with the case of `C:\Users\Username` where `Username` has _spaces_ in it (e.g. `Foo Bar`). It suggests encapsulating a string with spaces with quotes (e.g.): `C:\Users\"Foo Bar"`. Your issue  is similar because you use `KlausBgamer 13` without the quotes so that is interpreted as `KlausBgamer`. The [vastly] simpler solution is to _not_ use filenames with embedded spaces. You _can_ do it with spaces, but it complicates things.

Comment: @JosephLarson i can but i have some motives not to, maybe if it's the only way

Comment: You do not need to use the path from C:/ in a makefile!! Makefiles *always* use *relative paths only*

Comment: The usual for program development files is to use `_` instead of a space. But, also, you're hardcoding this path _everywhere_ in the makefile. Better to do (e.g.) `TOP = "C:\Users\whatever"` at the top and then use `$(TOP)/...` elsewhere. But, why not [in the shell], do `cd /path/to/top` and then have the makefile be current directory relative?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala im really not very good with those file things, how do i setup a relative path in this case

Comment: @CraigEstey my problem with the quotes is that as long as i build they dissapear

Comment: You're spelling out dependencies for each `.o` and hardwiring the full paths in each one. The compiler flags are pretty much identical. This needs to be simplified. Use more variables for the long paths at the top. And, how about wildcard dependencies like: `%.o: %.cpp`?

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This is prefaced by my top comments. It isn't a full solution, but I think you need to [greatly] simplify the makefile.

If you *must* hardwire full paths, use variables at the top of the file and use the variable names later in the makefile.

Don't hardwire/replicate huge amounts of duplicate/redundant code. Again, use variables.

Use wildcard dependencies. You can also use either `.vpath` or `VPATH` [for GNU make].

Here's a somewhat cleaned up version. It will probably still need a fair amount of work. The wildcard `%.o:` dependency is probably wrong. But it may give you some ideas:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
SHELL = $(ComSpec)
RMDIR = rmdir /s /q
RM = del /q
mymkdir = if not exist "$1" mkdir "$1"
else
RMDIR = rm -fr
RM = rm -f
mymkdir = mkdir -p $1
endif

TOP = "C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13"

ARD_TOP = "$(TOP)/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino"
ARD_VDIR = "$(ARD_TOP)/hardware/avr/1.8.3"
ARD_HW = "$(ARD_VDIR)/cores/arduino"
ARD_DEP = "$(ARD_HW)/abi.cpp core"
ARD_BIN = "$(ARD_TOP)/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy"
ARD_I += "-I$(ARD_HW)"
ARD_I += -I"$(ARD_VDIR)/variants/mega"

CFLAGS += -c -g -Os -w
CFLAGS += -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics
CFLAGS += -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560
CFLAGS += -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560
CFLAGS += -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR
CFLAGS += $(ARD_I)

LIB = "core.a"

PROJECT_OBJS = \
    project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.o \

PLATFORM_CORE_OBJS = \
    core/abi.cpp.o \
    core/CDC.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o \
    core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o \
    core/hooks.c.o \
    core/IPAddress.cpp.o \
    core/main.cpp.o \
    core/new.cpp.o \
    core/PluggableUSB.cpp.o \
    core/Print.cpp.o \
    core/Stream.cpp.o \
    core/Tone.cpp.o \
    core/USBCore.cpp.o \
    core/WInterrupts.c.o \
    core/wiring.c.o \
    core/wiring_analog.c.o \
    core/wiring_digital.c.o \
    core/wiring_pulse.c.o \
    core/wiring_pulse.S.o \
    core/wiring_shift.c.o \
    core/WMath.cpp.o \
    core/WString.cpp.o \

PLATFORM_VARIANT_OBJS = \

LIBRARIES_OBJS = \

TARGETS = \
    IR_Conversor.hex \

all: $(TARGETS)

IR_Conversor.hex: IR_Conversor.elf
    "$(ARD_BIN)/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "./IR_Conversor.elf" "./IR_Conversor.hex"

IR_Conversor.elf: $(PROJECT_OBJS) $(LIBRARIES_OBJS) core.a
    "$(ARD_BIN)/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega2560   -o "./IR_Conversor.elf" $(PROJECT_OBJS) $(LIBRARIES_OBJS)  "./core.a" "-L." -lm

core.a: $(PLATFORM_CORE_OBJS) $(PLATFORM_VARIANT_OBJS)

clean:
    -$(RMDIR) project core variant libraries
    -$(RM) *.hex *.eep *.bin *.elf *.a *.ar *.d

size:
    "$(ARD_BIN)/avr-size" -A "./IR_Conversor.elf"

project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.o: ../../IRCONVERSO.cpp project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "$(ARD_BIN)/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10608 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/cores/arduino" -I"C:/Users/KlausBgamer 13/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.3/variants/mega" "$<" -o "$@"

project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.d: ;

-include project/IRCONVERSO.cpp.d

core/%.o: $(ARD_HW)/cores/arduino/%.cpp core/%.cpp.d
    @$(call mymkdir,$(dir $@))
    "$(ARD_BIN)/avr-g++" $(CFLAGS) "$<" -o "$@"
    "$(ARD_BIN)/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "$LIB" "$@"

core/abi.cpp.d: ;

-include core/abi.cpp.d
```