# C++ Program Running on My Computer but throwing Clang error on another computer

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, clang++

I have programmed a simple program that gives a response to a user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void datenight();

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));;
    string redo;
    cout << "Hello and welcome to the date finder! (be sure not to make any typos!)" << endl;
    datenight();
    cout << "Would you like to choose another date? (type yes or no)";
    cin >> redo;
    while(redo == "yes"){
        datenight();
        cout << "Would you like to choose another date?";
        cin >> redo;
    }
    return 0;
}

void datenight(){
    string setting;
    string insidedate;
    string movietype;
    string season;
    string timeofday;
    string distance;
    string type;
    //to input more activities, add after the last item in the vector using comma and quotation marks.
    vector<string> dinners = {"protein pancakes", "veggie nuggets", "candlelight italian", "veggie burgers", "burritos", "Indian Food", "Pizza!", "gourmet oatmeal"};
    vector<string> restaurants = {"Cheesecake Factory!", "Sushi Place!", "Pho Place!", "Joe's", "Pizza House", "Frita Batido's", "Sava's", "Zingerman's", "Chapala"};
    vector<string> horrormovies = {"1BR", "As Above So Below", "Apostle", "1922", "Before I Wake", "Berlin Syndrome", "Bird Box", "The Blackcoat's Daughter"};
    vector<string> actionmovies = {"Olympus has Fallen", "A Marvel Movie!", "Extraction", "Outside the Wire", "Spenser Confidential", "The Departed", "NightCrawler", "Casino Royale", "Den of thieves", "Goodfellas", "Inception"};
    vector<string> otherinsideactivities = {"Do some online quizzes", "learn how to swing dance", "take a nap!", "do a lil workout", "do a lil indoor study date"};
    vector<string> romcoms = {"The Half of it", "After", "The Last Summer", "Always be my maybe", "To all the Boys I've Loved Before", "About Time", "Let it Snow", "Someone Great"};
    vector<string> autumnnightclose = {"Watch the sunset in the park", "night walk in the arb", "ice cream date!", "grab some food and chill on the diag", "see what our homies are doin"};
    vector<string> autumndayclose = {"Find somewhere to take some cute pictures","work out together!","walk to that park and skip rocks", "study date!", "Check out the art museum", "let's grab some boba tea", "check out the petting farm close by"};
    vector<string> autumndayfar = {"Petting Zooo", "Pumpkin Patch!", "Day Trip to Detroit", "Check out the Great Lakes", "Place with a lot of puppies", "Gun Range", "Axe Throwing", "Place to throw things"};
    vector<string> autumnnightfar = {"Go Stargazing :)", "Drive-In Movie", "Just. Drive.", "Go to a lake and watch the sunset"};
    vector<string> summerdayfar = {"drive up to pictured rocks", "go to the sand dunes up north", "do a beach trip", "do a Detroit Day Trip", "find a State Park to explore"};
    vector<string> winteractivities = {"go ice skating", "snowball fight", "build a snowman"};
    vector<string> superfar = {"Ski Trip!", "Austin, Texas", "Los Angeles, California", "Yosemite", "Grand Canyon", "That place in Washington from the Tiktok", "Vegas", "Out of the country?"};
    cout << endl;
    cout << "would you like to stay inside or go outside? (type inside or outside)" << endl;
    cin >> setting;
    //future improvements include more inside options.
    if(setting == "inside"){
        cout << "would you wanna make some food, watch a movie, or something else? (type food, movie, or other)" << endl;
        cin >> insidedate;
        if(insidedate == "food"){
            cout << dinners[rand()%(dinners.size())] << "! What do you think of that?" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if (insidedate == "other"){
            cout << "Hmmmm how about we " << otherinsideactivities[rand()%(otherinsideactivities.size())] << "?" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else{
            cout << "action, rom-com, or horror?" << endl;
            cin >> movietype;
            //movies are on Netflix but can probably expand.
            if(movietype == "horror"){
                cout << horrormovies[rand()%(horrormovies.size())] << " is what we're gonna watch today!" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(movietype == "action"){
                cout << actionmovies[rand()%(actionmovies.size())] << " is the plan for tonight!" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else{
                cout << romcoms[rand()%(romcoms.size())] << "sounds like a real mushy rom-com for tonight!" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    else{
        cout << "restaurant or an actual date? (type restaurant or else)" << endl;
        cin >> type;
        if(type == "restaurant"){
            cout << "what do you think about " << restaurants[rand()%(restaurants.size())] << "?" << endl;
            return;
        }
        cout << "what's the weather like outside? (type autumn, summer, or winter)" << endl;
        cin >> season;
        cout << "great! and are we going out in the daytime or nighttime (type day or night)?" << endl;
        cin >> timeofday;
        cout << "alright dope. now are we in ann arbor or should we drive a lil bit (type near, far, superfar)" << endl;
        cin >> distance;            
            if(distance == "superfar"){
                cout << "so what do we think about " << superfar[rand()%(superfar.size())] << "?" << endl;
            }
            if(season == "autumn" && timeofday == "night" && distance == "near"){
                cout << autumnnightclose[rand()%(autumnnightclose.size())] << " is what we plan on doing tonight!" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(season == "autumn" && timeofday == "day" && distance == "near"){   
                cout << autumndayclose[rand()%(autumndayclose.size())] << " is what we plan on doing today" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(season == "autumn" && timeofday == "day" && distance == "far"){
                cout << autumndayfar[rand()%(autumndayfar.size())] << " is what we plan on doing today" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(season == "autumn" && timeofday == "night" && distance == "far"){
                cout << autumnnightfar[rand()%(autumnnightfar.size())] << " is what we plan on doing tonight" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(season == "summer" && timeofday == "night" && distance == "far"){
                cout << autumnnightfar[rand()%(autumnnightfar.size())] << " is what we plan on doing tonight" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(season == "summer" && timeofday == "day" && distance == "far"){
                cout << summerdayfar[rand()%(summerdayfar.size())] << " is what we plan on doing today" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(season == "summer" && distance == "near"){
                cout << "it's summmer cmoonnnnn lets go somewhere outside of Ann Arbor" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(season == "winter" && timeofday == "day"){
                cout << "I couldn't come up with many winter activities so I highly suggest we stay inside, but one thing we could do is " << winteractivities[rand()%(winteractivities.size())] << endl;
                return;
            }
    }
return;
}
```

right now, it compiles and runs properly on my computer. I am using WSL-Ubuntu and bash. My computer is a windows computer and the other one is a Macbook. The other computer is also using zsh instead of bash.

The exact error is
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Program Name'
clang: error: no input files

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Does a simple `printf("hello\n");` compile and run on the Mac. I'm afraid it's an installation problem, and your source code has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Does the Macbook have clang installed?

Comment: I see "windows" and `Program Name`. It appears that on windows, one or more pathname components have spaces in them [anathema on linux and macOS]. Be sure your makefile encapsulates such pathnames with quotes (e.g.) `DIR = "C:\Program Name\foo\bar"`. Then, put quotes around usage (e.g.) `all: ;` and `echo "$DIR"` See my recent answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052225/how-do-i-fix-no-rule-to-make-target-c-users-klausbgamer-needed-by-core/66053682#66053682

Comment: @Eljay On macOS, `clang` _is_ installed by default and `gcc` is just a symlink to it.